Remote tcp connexion to postgresql not responding
I can't connect to my remote postgresql server.
I'm on a local network containing my server (192.168.1.2) and my development workstation (192.168.1.3). I can't connect to my database on port 5432. My server receives TCP frames but does not respond. The other protocols SSH, HTTP are working. However, I can connect to the database on my server on interfaces 127.0.0.1 and 192.168.1.2.
On my server, I've modified the pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf files, adding the lines host and listen_addresses = '*'. Port 5432 is open and listening.
The strange thing is that my workstation sends requests on my server's port (tcpdump below) but doesn't respond (no ack).
Everything seems correct but it doesn't work. Do you have any idea ? What am I missing?
DJANGO SETTINGS
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'ering',
        'USER': 'marika',
        'PASSWORD': '123456789',
        'HOST': '192.168.1.2',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

PG_HBA.CONF
local   all             postgres                                peer
local   all             all                                     trust
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    all             all             ::/0                    md5

SYSTEMCTL STATUS
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Mon 2024-08-12 11:26:25 CEST; 4min 37s ago
    Process: 418829 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 418829 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 1ms

Aug 12 11:26:25 astro systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Aug 12 11:26:25 astro systemd[1]: Finished PostgreSQL RDBMS.

IPTABLES
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:postgresql

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-reply

TCPDUMP
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on enp9s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
11:30:33.611720 IP 192.168.1.3.12940 > astro.postgresql: Flags [S], seq 432697152, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
11:30:34.623543 IP 192.168.1.3.12940 > astro.postgresql: Flags [S], seq 432697152, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
11:30:36.627325 IP 192.168.1.3.12940 > astro.postgresql: Flags [S], seq 432697152, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
11:30:40.629432 IP 192.168.1.3.12940 > astro.postgresql: Flags [S], seq 432697152, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0

NETSTATS
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      423091/postgres
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      876/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      423091/postgres
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      918/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::9983                 :::*                    LISTEN      9147/coolwsd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      918/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::4949                 :::*                    LISTEN      2021/perl
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      876/sshd: /usr/sbin


This sounds like a firewall issue.  Was tcpdump run on the client or on the server? And what was it that was being dumped?

Thanks for the answer, the tcpdump was done on the server (astro.postgresql) listening on port 5432, the requests come from the client (192.168.1.3). As you can see with my Iptables, the port 5432 is open and listening

have you check allow host in psql conf file?

Yes, I have set these lines in psql config :
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
host all all ::/0 md5
And I did set the listen_addresses line = '*'.

This looks like purely a networking issue.  I can't imagine either PostgreSQL or Django have anything specific to do with it.

Yes, I agree. I think it may be a socket problem, but the truth is I really don't understand what the problem is.
